# Make Jquery X tabbable

Tags: jquery

So I am working on some accessibility issues with our jquery dialogs and the problem I've run into is how to make the X or close button tabbable so it can be focused and closed using the key board. Is that possible?

UPDATE:
It is a jquery UI dialog. Here is some code:

```
element.dialog(someService.getDefaultPopupProperties);
```

default properties:

```
function getDefaultPopupProperties()
    {
        var popupDefaults = {
            position: 'center',
            title: '',
            autoOpen:false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeText: '',
            appendTo: '.iv360-appContainer',
            width: '800',
            height: '400',
            // Default Popup Buttons is now an Array, with "Cancel" at index 0, and "Submit" at index 1
            buttons: [
                {
                    'text': translationService.getMessage('CANCEL'),
                    'class': 'secondaryButton',
                    'click': angular.noop,
                    'id': 'POPUP_CANCEL_BUTTON'
                },
                {
                    'text': translationService.getMessage('SUBMIT'),
                    'click': angular.noop,
                    'id': 'POPUP_SUBMIT_BUTTON'
                }
            ],
            open: function(event, ui) {
                //disable main div scrolling
                jq360(".iv360-appContainer").addClass('ui360-behind-dialog');
            },
            close: function(event, ui) {
                //re-enable main div scrolling
                jq360(".iv360-appContainer").removeClass('ui360-behind-dialog');
            }
        };

        return popupDefaults;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the jQuery UI dialog or something you built in-house? The close button appears tabbable in the jQuery UI and is layered with the appropriate ARIA tags. Do you have an example you can show with details?

Comment: Does the example code in the jQuery UI demo work for you? (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). The close button is tabbable for me in IE10 and Chrome using Windows 7. What browser are you testing in? OS?  Are you running JAWS or any other accessibility software during testing?

Comment: So this is an angular.js application and I have narrowed the problem. It looks like in the body of the modal there is a button with an ng-disabled on it. When I remove that tabbing works just fine. Ill repost a different question to see if anyone else has seen that happen. Thanks for the help. +1.